# Carousel with Thumbnails in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, slider, carousel, thumbnails

I need to make Bootstrap 3.0 Carousel to display a slide of thumbnails. How can I do this?
This is an image of what I´m looking for:

[image: Bootstrap 3.0 Carousel Thumbs]

This is a working example for Bootstrap 2, but I need this for Bootstrap 3.0.: [Bootstrap Thumbnail Slider](http://www.bootply.com/63984)

Comment: Can i get a working example of this in html ? All links are broken .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4 (update 2019)**

A multi-item carousel can be accomplished in several ways [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once/20008623#20008623). Another option is to use [separate thumbnails to navigate the carousel slides](https://www.codeply.com/go/tBbcVXe1xZ).

**Bootstrap 3 (original answer)**

This can be done using the grid inside each carousel item.

```
       <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">..
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">..
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">..
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">..
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    ...add more item(s)
                 </div>
        </div>
```

Demo example thumbnail slider using the carousel:
 http://www.bootply.com/81478

Another example with carousel indicators as thumbnails:
http://www.bootply.com/79859

Comment: Great example but... how can i make this responsive?

Comment: It is responsive.. Do you want it to be full width? or change the layout based on different displays/devices?

Comment: If you minimize the window the elements are listed below, thats the problem.

Comment: @ZimSystem when prev and next is click i want the slided to move by only one thumbnail at a time(not all 4), how can I do it?

Answer (score 9):

@Skelly 's answer is correct.  It won't let me add a comment (<50 rep)... but to answer your question on his answer: In the example he linked, if you add

```
col-xs-3
```

class to each of the thumbnails, like this:

```
class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"
```

then it should stay the way you want it when sized down to phone width.

Answer (score 4):

Just found out a great plugin for this:

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Regards

Comment: While I like flexslider, the question was specifically regarding Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Unfortunately it is licensed under the GPL

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the carousel's indicators to display thumbnails.
2. Position the thumbnails outside of the main carousel with CSS.
3. Set the maximum height of the indicators to not be larger than the thumbnails.
4. Whenever the carousel has slid, update the position of the indicators, positioning the active indicator in the middle of the indicators.

I'm using this on my site (for example [here](http://babakfakhamzadeh.com/article/fordlandia-visions-of-pasts-future)), but I'm using some extra stuff to do lazy loading, meaning extracting the code isn't as straightforward as I would like it to be for putting it in a fiddle.

Also, my templating engine is [smarty](http://smarty.net/), but I'm sure you get the idea.

The meat...

Updating the indicators:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    {assign var='walker' value=0}
    {foreach from=$item["imagearray"] key="key" item="value"}
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{$walker}"{if $walker == 0} class="active"{/if}>
            <img src='http://farm{$value["farm"]}.static.flickr.com/{$value["server"]}/{$value["id"]}_{$value["secret"]}_s.jpg'>
        </li>

        {assign var='walker' value=1 + $walker}
    {/foreach}
</ol>
```

Changing the CSS related to the indicators:

```
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom:-50px;
    height: 36px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    text-indent: 0;
    width: 34px !important;
    height: 34px !important;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.carousel-indicators li img {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.carousel-indicators li:hover img, .carousel-indicators li.active img {
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    border-color: #337ab7;
}
```

When the carousel has slid, update the list of thumbnails:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    var widthEstimate = -1 * $(".carousel-indicators li:first").position().left + $(".carousel-indicators li:last").position().left + $(".carousel-indicators li:last").width(); 
    var newIndicatorPosition = $(".carousel-indicators li.active").position().left + $(".carousel-indicators li.active").width() / 2;
    var toScroll = newIndicatorPosition + indicatorPosition;
    var adjustedScroll = toScroll - ($(".carousel-indicators").width() / 2);
    if (adjustedScroll < 0)
        adjustedScroll = 0;

    if (adjustedScroll > widthEstimate - $(".carousel-indicators").width())
        adjustedScroll = widthEstimate - $(".carousel-indicators").width();

    $('.carousel-indicators').animate({ scrollLeft: adjustedScroll }, 800);

    indicatorPosition = adjustedScroll;
});
```

And, when your page loads, set the initial scroll position of the thumbnails:

```
var indicatorPosition = 0;
```

Comment: See I did something very similar. But I have a problem where the images in the slider don't show up even though at all. The main image in the carousel shows up and keeps cycling through a list without a problem, but the thumbnails never show up. To note, there are over 100+ images I'm trying to display so I'm not sure if that causes any problems.