# Looking for a BootStrap 3.0 carousel photo gallery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Anyone aware of a plugin for BS 3.0 that creates a simple or minimal thumbnail driven slideshow that does not use a light box? Responsive is ideal as well.

I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel but haven't found anything and am kind of in a rush.

saw this, [Carousel with Thumbnails in Bootstrap 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850099/carousel-with-thumbnails-in-bootstrap-3-0)

I don't like how redundant it is having to repeat the same slides to fake thumbnails.

I'm not oppose to coding one myself, I was just hoping to save some time and utilize a plugin if someone had already produced one.

Below is a pic of what i'm thinking. sizes aren't relevant.

[image: ignore pic sizes but this is what i'm looking to achieve]

If no one has anything I'll share what i end up coding after i make time for it.

Thanks!

Comment: Flexslider and Slick both have synched options to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into these. Wish whomever -1 this would comment why. I felt after exhausting Google asking peers was a legit step, perhaps I misunderstood the point of this website?

Comment: I usually never negative vote, so it wasn't me, but this site is for code you need help with, not recommendations.

Comment: Fair enough. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Bootply example might be helpful: http://www.bootply.com/79859

```
            <!-- thumb navigation carousel items -->
          <ul class="list-inline">
          <li> <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>
          <li> <a id="carousel-selector-1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=two" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>
          <li> <a id="carousel-selector-2">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>
          <li> <a id="carousel-selector-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=four" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>
                <li> <a id="carousel-selector-4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=five" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>
          <li> <a id="carousel-selector-5">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=six" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>
          <li> <a id="carousel-selector-6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=seven" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>
          <li> <a id="carousel-selector-7">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=eight" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>
            </ul>

    </div>


    <!-- main slider carousel -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="slider">

                <div class="col-md-12" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                        <!-- main slider carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480/888/FFF" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=four" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=five" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=six" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="6">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=seven" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="7">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=eight" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- main slider carousel nav controls --> <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/main slider carousel-->

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. pretty much what I was looking to accomplish functionally. Thanks.

Comment: How can we add carousel functionality to thumbnails as well so that they only appear in one line when they are large in number?