# Add bootstrap carousel into thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

**Hi**

I want to know if there is a solution to add a bootstrap carousel into a given thumbnail to have like a slider (image slider).

***for ex:***

```
<div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <div class = "thumbnail">
             <img src = "/bootstrap/images/kittens.jpg" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail">
          </div>

          <div class = "caption">
             <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
             <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>

             <p>
                <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary" role = "button">
                   Button
                </a> 

                <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default" role = "button">
                   Button
                </a>
             </p>

          </div>
       </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3

Comment: what's the layout you needed in the carousel? is it only thumbnail? or one big image and thumbnails below?

Comment: I want a carousel inside the thumbnail to show many images one by one like in Airbnb search when you can see rooms without accessing to whole page detail

Comment: please check the answer provided and response

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example.
 This can be done using the grid inside each carousel item.

https://www.bootply.com/81478

Mentioned in [Carousel with Thumbnails in Bootstrap 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850099/carousel-with-thumbnails-in-bootstrap-3-0)

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
         <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-3">..
                  </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">..
                  </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">..
                  </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">..
                  </div>
             </div>
             <!--/row-->
           </div>
             ...add more item(s)
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet. Have added two carousels, you can repeat the process

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <h3 style="text-align: center;">Test 1</h3>
    </div>

   
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <h3 style="text-align: center;">Test 2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="myCarousel3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel3" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel3" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel3" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <h3 style="text-align: center;">Test 3</h3>
    </div>

 
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="myCarousel4" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel4" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel4" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel4" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel4" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel4" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <h3 style="text-align: center;">Test 4</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```